# What does the version of a ruby gem have to do with the version of ruby used during development?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, versioning

I've been reading on [rubygems.org](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#semantic-versioning) about leveraging the semantic versioning pattern for Ruby gems.

For example, I might want to use some ruby gem named `library` that includes all minor updates starting from `v2.2` up to but not including `v3.0`. I can add it as a run-time dependency in my `gemspec` or my `Gemfile`:

some_gem.gemspec:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'library','~> 2.2'
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'library', '~> 2.2'
```

I also know we can specify which version of ruby we'd like to use using a ruby version management like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

For example, I've also set the local ruby version to `system` (on macOS) before with:

```
rbenv local system
```

Which generated a `.ruby-version` file in the project root.

I'm confused about what the ruby version a gem author uses has to do with the gem version. Are they related? How, would a gem author manage the version of ruby? Do gem author publish gems for multiple ruby versions?

For example, if an author uses `2.3.1` to build her gem does that mean someone with only `system` ruby would not be able to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ruby version specification is optional, and just used to help developers consume the gem easier. For example there are many 2.3 gems that don't have the [required_ruby_version](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#required_ruby_version) set. If you try to run these on 1.9 you might get errors, but they won't explicitly say that the ruby version is wrong, so they'll be harder to debug.

By the way, you can have 2.3 as system ruby - `sudo apt-get install ruby2.3`